# Apply a mask to GWT TextInputCell

Tags: gwt

I have overridden GWT TextInputCell.onBrowserEvent() to restrict input length and content.
I want to apply an input mask to format the input as the user types:
Enter 1234567890 and it is transformed to 123-456-7890 (telephone number).

I'd like to maintain the format during editing, such that a partial value is allowed
and dashes will be preserved in the partial value as well.
It would be nicer still to display the mask at all times, with blank space placeholders.

How do I determine, for each keystroke, where the cursor is within the input value?
In other words, I want to get the index of the value that's about to be added, deleted, etc.

Thanks in advance, any advice, examples appreciated.

Comment: You can adapt this MaskedTextBox https://code.google.com/p/efmi/source/browse/src/com/arcbees/amm/client/ui/MaskedTextBox.java?repo=version2  to your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I did not check back here till now. I came up with a simple solution using KeyPress, KeyUp and Blur handlers for TextBox and analogous processing for TextInputCell. The provided code seems more generic and I will work on adapting it. I'll post my results when I get it working.